# How to broadcast operands with same shape?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I get error when --> 73 rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(predictions - y_test)**2)
74 print(f"RMSE: {rmse}")
75

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (41,1) (101,1)
How do i fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import yfinance as yf

# Download the AAPL stock price data from Yahoo Finance
symbol = 'AAPL'
start_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365 * 2)
end_date = datetime.now()
df = yf.download(symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date)

# Extract the daily adjusted closing price data
data = df.filter(['Adj Close']).values

# Scale the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
print(scaler)
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
training_data_len = int(len(data) * 0.8)
train_data = scaled_data[:training_data_len, :]
test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len:, :]

# Prepare the training data
x_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i, 0])

# Convert the data to numpy arrays
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

# Reshape the data for the LSTM model
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

# Build the LSTM model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(25))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1)

# Prepare the testing data
x_test = []
y_test = data[training_data_len:, :]
for i in range(60, len(test_data)):
    x_test.append(test_data[i-60:i, 0])

# Convert the data to numpy arrays
x_test = np.array(x_test)

# Reshape the data for the LSTM model
print("1")
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))
print("2")
# Get the model's predicted price values
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
print("3")
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

# Calculate the root mean squared error (RMSE)
```

rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(predictions - y_test)**2)
print(f"RMSE: {rmse}")

```
# Plot the data
train = data[:training_data_len, :]
valid = data[training_data_len:, :]
valid['Predictions'] = predictions
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('LSTM Model')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Adj Close Price')
plt.plot(train['Adj Close'])
plt.plot(valid[['Adj Close', 'Predictions']])
plt.legend(['Train', 'Valid', 'Predictions'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()

# Make predictions for the next 10 days
last_60_days = data[-60:]
last_60_days_scaled = scaler.transform(last_60_days)
X_test = []
X_test.append(last_60_days_scaled)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
predicted_price = model.predict(X_test)
predicted_price = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_price)
#print(f"Predicted price for the next day: ${predicted_price[0][0]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're defining `y_test` incorrectly.  Based on how you're defining x_test with a 60-day window, try defining `y_test` to instead be

```
y_test = scaled_data[training_data_len + 60:, :]
```